# OCaml defining and implementing interface

Tags: ocaml

Let's have such code

```
module type INTERFACE =
sig
  val function_that_must_be_implemented : int -> int
end

module Implementation : INTERFACE = 
struct
  let function_that_must_be_implemented x = x
end
```

Is any way to describe the same thing but using OCaml classes? I want to have a class that implements such interface.

Comment: In F#, this is a commonplace thing to do (keyword ``with``). Not really an OCAML programmer, but maybe you get lucky and the F# solution is the same or similar to the OCAML solution?!

Comment: Or read https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/classes.html to see the OCAML way of doing things...

Answer (score 3):

There is something called a class type:

```
class type interface = object method method_I_want : int end
```

Then you can implement it:

```
class implementation : interface = object
    method method_I_want = 14
end
```

You can indeed instantiate this class:

```
# let abc = new implementation;;
val abc : implementation = <obj>
# abc#method_I_want;;
- : int = 14
```